# Replacing multiple string elements from column

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, ssis

I'm trying to clean a column of text that I have in a SQL server database (in Azure in case that matters).

The text contains peoples names, with lots of affixes (dr., Prof., M.D., PhD., MSC, and lots of dubious characters that I don't want`,;,;,` `(, )` etc

There are so many things I want to strip out of these rows - often multiple times in a single field - that I had thought the best way would be to add them to a table and use this to run through and replace each and every one with a space, before finally trimming and replacing multiple spaces with a single one, as a nested replace formula looks insane when putting even just 1/3 of all the terms I need to strip out of the column.

Finally - the output I want is to have the name split into the 1st name, middle name, surname. All nice and clean, with no other info.

I've been processing the data so far in SSIS, and have explored standard T-SQL transformations (using nested replace(), but which grew so much that it was obscene). I've explored Derived columns - again it seems nested replace is the only realistic option here!? I've finally been trying to find a solution using a scripted component, but being a rank amateur on this, I've been unable to fathom out how to use it and haven't found any examples either.

Efficiency is also a concern, as I've circa 800,000 names to process initially.

I'd be very grateful for any help with this matter, as I've been searching for a long time but have found nothing that seems to help directly.

Comment: You're going down a rabbit hole. Take a few minutes to read [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). It scratches the surface of the considerations for the task at hand.

Comment: I would consider [Data Quality Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/data-quality-services/data-quality-services?view=sql-server-2017) or custom external application written in any convenient language. Problem is extremely broad.

Comment: Thanks for the comments:Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names - The only fortunate part of this task is that 99% (95%?) accuracy is absolutely fine for this, and I will retain the original name for complete identification for the final stage of our process.

Comment: Thanks also for the comment on Data Quality Services - but the top of the page says this isnt relevant for an Azure SQL database, so not sure I could consider this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rabbit hole, challenges of full names stored in one field and then parsing that in T-SQL and all the disclaimers aside.

Cleansing data, particularly text/varchar/nvarchar columns is a challenge regardless of the items mentioned above,  as you have a found nested REPLACE can get out of control and difficult to manage.

There's a couple of things you can do in t-sql to maybe help with what you're trying to accomplish.  All this will require multiple passes on the data. I see this broken down into 2 "categories" of cleaning.  1 - remove defined words, 2 - special characters.

- Put the "words", in your case name prefix and suffix, into a table that you want to strip out.
- Strip out basically all non-alpha characters.

What if my name prefix or suffix is "Dean" or "Miss" or ... and name is "Dean Smith" or "Missy" or... , yup there it is, rabbit hole.  Setting that aside, here's some example code you can give a try.

```
--Test table for words I want to strip out.
DECLARE @WordsToRemove TABLE
    (
        [word] NVARCHAR(200)
    );

--Test table for my data I want to clean
DECLARE @TestData TABLE
    (
        [Data] NVARCHAR(500)
      , [CleanData] NVARCHAR(500)
    );

--Flag I am using to keep my while loops going
DECLARE @Continue INT;


--Insert of the words I want to remove.
INSERT INTO @WordsToRemove (
                         [word]
                     )
VALUES ( 'DR' )
     , ( 'D.R.' )
     , ( 'M.D.' )
     , ( 'md' )
     , ( 'Prof.' );

--Insert test names to clean.  I have a while loop here, was loading my test table with 10000+ recrods to see performance.
--You can leave the while loop here commented out just to see how the code works.  I got under 2 minutes for 100000+ records.  Your mileage may vary.
--WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   @TestData) < 100000
    --BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @TestData (
                              [Data]
                          )
        VALUES ( N'DR Jimmy Smith' )
             , ( 'D.R. John Jones M.D.' )
             , ( 'Timothy Neal DR md' )
             , ( 'Prof. Bob Smith Dr M.D.' )
             , ( 'Taco;,,; Johns Dr. Prof.' )
             , ( 'Prof. ''#%^Special Charaters;,,; Dr. Prof.' );
    --END;

--Just updating a another column so I can save original state
UPDATE @TestData
SET    [CleanData] = [Data]


--Join to my @WordsToRemove table using PATINDEX, continue doing that until all occurrences have been removed.
--Clean out words we dont want
SET @Continue = 1;
WHILE @Continue = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @Continue = 0;
        UPDATE     [a]
        SET        [a].[CleanData] = REPLACE([a].[CleanData], [b].[word], '')
                 , @Continue = 1
        FROM       @TestData [a]
        INNER JOIN @WordsToRemove [b]
            ON PATINDEX('%' + [b].[word] + '%', [a].[CleanData]) > 0;
    END;

--Remove all non-alpha characters, preserving spaces
--PATINDEX using "%[^a-z ]%" looks of anything not a character and not a space.
SET @Continue = 1;
WHILE @Continue = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @Continue = 0;
        UPDATE [a]
        SET    [a].[CleanData] = STUFF([a].[CleanData], PATINDEX('%[^a-z ]%', [a].[CleanData]), 1, '')
             , @Continue = 1
        FROM   @TestData [a]
        WHERE  PATINDEX('%[^a-z ]%', [a].[CleanData]) > 0;
    END;

SELECT *
FROM   @TestData;
```

Then from there, based on whatever format your data is stored in, extract each part you're after.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Tim. I have actually used T-SQL/SSIS in a number of passes to get the results required. I've marked this as correct as the method I utilised to solve my problem basically seems to mirror exactly the logic you provided at the top of your answer. (I haven't tested any of the code you provided though I should add, in case it isn't suitable to anyone who may look at this thread later). Thanks for everyone's time. problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

This only addresses part of the question, however, i wanted to elaborate on this point of splitting names. i don't expect voets here, but a comment isn't going to provide the space.

Firstly *"Finally - the output I want is to have the name split into 1st name, middle name, surname. All nice and clean, with no other info."* not going to happen. Names have far too many variations. Have a read of [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/), it might seem silly, but it's very true.

Say, for example, you **assume** (wrongly), that a name is split into several parts, delimited by whitespace. The first partthe Title, Second the First name, Last is the Surname and anything in between are Middle Names. Take these examples:

```
Mr John Smith
Mrs Jane Alice Wallis Smith
Mr Dick van Dyke
Sarah Brown
```

Obviously, to start, for the first person, "John" is his first name, "Smith" the surname, and Mr the Title. What about the second? is Wallis a middle name? if might be a double barrel surname (how do you know?) What about the last person? "van Dyke" is the full surname. Then you have the last entry, where the title is even missing; what happens there?

Like i said, you can't split a name using a SQL. You would have to have some **very** clever machine learning tools to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, as I mentioned in a comment response just now - some incorrect data is absolutely fine in this process as the final stage will be to manually process some highlights of the data, so I will retain the full unadulterated original name for future references.